# Federated Single Sign-On to AWS Using Google Apps

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-sso, aws-sso

We have had everything working perfectly for the last couple of years, then all of a sudden in the last week we cant log into AWS using the Google SSO.

We are setting up the roles for the users again (as per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-single-sign-on-to-aws-using-google-apps/), but when we get to the users.patch (or users.update) section with the following call (values for <role ARN>,<provider ARN> replaced with actual...):

```
  "customSchemas": {
    "SSO": {
      "role": [
        {
          "value": "<role ARN>,<provider ARN>",
          "customType": "iPDA-sysadmin"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

We get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Input: Bad request for ",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Input: Bad request for ",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be great...

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6327792?hl=en

You need to pass in the type as well.

```
{
  "customSchemas": 
  {
    "SSO": 
    {
      "role": [
      {
       "value": "<role ARN>,<provider ARN>",
       "type": "custom"
       "customType": "SSO"
       
      }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```